# Subdomain routing in loopback to multiple static files (angular apps)

Tags: node.js, angular, express, url-routing, loopbackjs

I've got two angular 2 client apps that I'd like to serve from my loopback backend. I've been able to serve them successfully from subdirectories (`www.mysite.com/subdirectory`), but I'm trying to serve them from subdomains (`www.subdomain.mysite.com`).

Loopback doesn't seem to have a built in way to handle subdomain routing through the middleware or anywhere else that I can see. So I'm trying to accomplish the routing by matching the hostname in a url-not-found-handler that is set for `final` in the middleware.json file as such:

```
  if (req.hostname.match(/subdomain1\./g)) {
    console.log('requesting subdomain1 site')
    res.sendFile(path.resolve() + '/dist/subdomain1/index.html')
  } else if (req.hostname.match(/subdomain2\./g)) {
    console.log('requesting subdomain2 site')
    res.sendFile(path.resolve() + '/dist/subdomain/index.html')
  } else {
    next();
  }
```

I've also got the static files in the middleware.json set up as such:

```
  "files": {
      "loopback#static": [
        {
          "name": "subdomain1",
          "params": "dist/subdomain1"
        },
        {
          "name": "subdomain2",
          "params": "dist/subdomain2"
        }
    ]
  }
```

This seems to work in that it properly matches and sends the correct index.html file. I know it's the right index.html by inspecting in the browser.

**But for some reason the actual angular app that gets served *ALWAYS* is whatever is first in the `loopback#static` array. If I have subdomain2 first, that will be shown for both subdomain1.mysite.com as well as subdomain2.mysite.com.**

How can I fix this issue and serve a different apps based on the subdomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out a solution. Don't think `loopback` has a built in way of handling this, so got it to work with the following:

Cleared the files section from middleware.json

```
"files": {}
```

Used a combination of `vhost` and `serve-static` to deliver based on the subdomain

```
var vhost = require('vhost');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');

var serveSubdomain1 = serveStatic('dist/subdomain1', {'index': ['index.html']})
var serveSubdomain2 = serveStatic('dist/subdomain2', {'index': ['index.html']})

app.use(vhost('subdomain1.mysite', serveSubdomain1));
app.use(vhost('subdomain2.mysite', serveSubdomain2));
```